# How to upload a photo to a website I own?

Tags: html, upload, web, jpeg

This question may be so startling obvious to some of you that I'm almost too embarrassed to ask it, but it's new to me and I don't know anyone I can ask.

I own a website which is hosted and "up and running". I haven't really done anything with it. A colleague put up a home page a long time ago.

All I am trying to do is learn how to upload

(1) A text file containing HTML
(2) A photo

The photo's URL would only need to be www.mywebsite.com/pic.jpg. I don't want to embed it or anything.

I am trying to learn how to do this from basics, in other words I do not want to use any specific software or web editing tools. I simply want to learn the method of telling my PC "Upload this text file to www.mywebsite.com/textfile.html". I am sure there is a password.  I don't know what it is offhand but there are only about 10 things it could be.

I am comfortable using the command prompt, in case that helps.
I use Windows 7.

I would be very grateful if someone could give me a series of bullets points with specific steps (rather than a general idea of how to do it). There may be other ways to do it using software, but that is not the purpose of this exercise.

I do hope I've been clear. Do please ask if I've not given enough information.

Comment: How to upload is very different from provider to provider, you'll need to at least know where the web site is hosted (and the company that hosts it will most likely have better instructions online than people can easily provide here)

Comment: Please provide us with the company that is hosting your website. Otherwise it is very hard to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discover (with your ISP) the **ftp address** of your site, the relative **username** and **password** for this access and the **root folder** of your site. With this in hand, use a Client FTP software (there are plenty of them, easy and free to use) to access your site by FTP and proceed with a simple "copy file" from your local machine to the **root folder** of your website. As easy as you would do with your Windows Explorer. Best.

Comment: Thank you, statosdotcom.  Thanks also to Joachim Isaksson and Laurens.